# How to change resolution of a video.mp4 file stored on the AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I'm using `AWS S3` to store my `video` and `audio` files. Before I upload any video file, I convert the video file into different resolutions from my laptop using `ffmpeg` and then I upload those files onto my `AWS S3` account. I want to know if its possible to convert the video file stored on my `AWS S3` to different resolutions. As in the conversion to happen on the `AWS`.

I'm using `ffmpeg` command in `CMD`: `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -s 256x144 -c:a copy video_144p.mp4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up a transcoding pipeline with [AWS Elastic Transcoder](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/details/). It allows you to take objects from one S3 bucket, transcode the objects (change frame rate, resolution, etc.), and put the altered versions in a different S3 bucket. You could set it up to transcode to multiple different resolutions outputted to different S3 buckets if you wanted.

Comment: Are they using `ffmpeg` for changing resolutions